# Schedule apex one time

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, cron

I am planning to schedule apex from my class if it meets certain conditions. Is it possible to schedule apex for a single time? If yes is it done using Cron expression or any other method.

Answer (score 10):

If your class implements `Database.Batchable`, you can also use `System.scheduleBatch` to run a batch **X** minutes in the future. This negates the need for a scheduled class entirely. You can also daisy chain these together if you want to run perpetually every **X** minutes by calling the batch again in the finish method.

Answer (score 6):

Cron expression can we used to run job for any given time. You can schedule for with following expression

```
0 0 5 1 MAR ? 2019
```

which means run on 
[image]

You can use following tool to generate your cron expression: http://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Please note that Salesforce doesn't allow wildcard for seconds and minutes. Refer following table for valid cron expression value

[image]

Comment: You've mentioned this tool before, but you should mention that some actual cron expressions are not valid in Apex, such as second or minute wildcards.

Answer (score 3):

From the document - [Run a scheduled Apex job once](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000002809&type=1)

Using Scheduled Apex UI you can not set a scheduled class to run only once, it's always recurring. So, you'll need to use `System.scheduled` via the system log to implement a workaround.

After the apex is scheduled, Abort the job by adding a `finish` method to your class that implements the `Schedulable` Interface. This stops the job from running more than once.

**Example code for running a job 10 minutes from now only once**

```
String hour = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().hour());
String min = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().minute() + 10); String ss = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().second());

//parse to cron expression
String nextFireTime = ss + ' ' + min + ' ' + hour + ' * * ?';

MyScheduledJob s = new MyScheduledJob(); System.schedule('Job Started At ' + String.valueOf(Datetime.now()), nextFireTime, s);
```

Comment: Also, what should I do to schedule it every 10 min

Comment: You have to schedule your batch for 6 times, if you want to run batch for every 10 mints.Go through this - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170829/scheduled-apex-to-run-every-10-minutes

Comment: @Ishan [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119655) and its linked questions discuss scheduling less than hourly granularity.

Comment: @sfdcfox should I delete this question because I think it is duplicate

Comment: @Ishan A question about scheduling a job "just once" I don't think has ever been clearly answered. Scheduling on a schedule is definitely a duplicate.

Comment: You can schedule one via ui. Set it to run on say Monday and set the end date for Tuesday's date for example

Comment: Is it me or does the code here schedule this to run "10 minutes from now" every day not just "right now"? I'm a cron noob so apologies if I'm missing something.